# Error in first attempt Ruby webcrawler

Tags: ruby

I am creating a basic scraper that gets the total relief amount rewarded to each state and then displays it, but I'm receiving an error I don't understand. Can you help me fix my program please?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'crack'
require 'open-uri'

URL = 'http://www.recovery.gov/pages/GetXmlData.aspx?data=recipientHomeMap'

Crack::XML.parse(open(URL).read)['totals']['state'].each do |state|
  puts ['id', 'awarded', 'received', 'jobs'].map{|f| state[f]}.join(', ')
end
```

rb:7:in ' : undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass(NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

Check what `Crack::XML.parse(open(URL).read)` return

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting anything back from `Crack::XML.parse(open(URL).read)`

You are trying to access values from `nil` hence the `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Make sure you are actually getting the file first.